# polymer 1.0 event when element appears on page

Tags: event-handling, polymer, polymer-1.0

I can't understand how to make css animations to an element no sooner than it appears on page, like css3 transform rotate. when I set in `attached(){performRotation()}` when the element appears on page it's already rotated. I couldn't find in all documentation which event I need to subscribe to in order to start animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the help of  `NeonAnimatableBehavior` and `NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior`, you may configure your animations in `animationConfig` property and then play them with `playAnimation('name')` function which is implemented by `NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior` .

Please check [lifecycle callbacks](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#lifecycle-callbacks) and [neon-animation demos](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=neon-animated-pages&view=demo:demo/index.html).

```
behaviors: [
  Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior,
  Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
],

properties: {
  animationConfig: { ... },
}

...

ready: function() {
  this.playAnimation('entry');
}
```

I've made you a [simple example](http://codepen.io/MWalid/full/KpZpMz/) using the above elements to give you a quick start.

**Update**

You can modify each configured animation based on given properties in one of the lifecycle callbacks, e.g. `ready` callback:

```
var entryAnimation = this.animationConfig.entry[0];
entryAnimation.transformFrom = this.doSomethingTo(this.someProperty);
```

Please check the updated [demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/full/KpZpMz/).

Comment: Thanks? that helped to get it going, it turnes out I wasn't including Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior.
though one question persists: how can I call properties from inside animationConfig? Even if it's 
`
propersties:{
  min:{type:Number,value:60},
  animationConfig:{
   ...
    transformTo: 'rotate('+this.min+'deg)'
   ...
  }
}`

Comment: thank you very much! I hope it appears in documentation, because before it wasn't clear

Comment: @JohnArcher it is in the demos